# I use FCPX, curious on how I can put a non-360 clip into a 360 video?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, 360video

I have some drone footage that is not in 360 that I really want to put into my 360 video. Everything else is shot in 360, is there a way to show the non-360 clip without it looking terrible?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [Dashwood 360 VR](http://www.dashwood3d.com/360vrtoolbox.php) plug-ins have a plug-in called Project 2D on Sphere that allows you to put 2D footage into your 360° panorama:

> The Project 2D on Sphere plugin can be used to place logos in your 2:1 equirectangular projection

It has a variety of other useful tools, too.